# Execute Laravel controller first instead of a modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, iframe

I am using Laravel as a PHP framework. And I am using an iframe (as a modal) where I show a form. So, what I want to do is if a user is not logged in, don't show the modal at all, but I am getting a modal even if the user is not logged in.

This is my controller

```
   public function index()
    //If logged in return back
   {       
        if (auth()->guard('web')->check())
        {   
            return back()->withMessage('you are already logged in');
        }
 return view('myview');
```

So, a modal is shown where it redirects back, but I don't want to show it in the iframe modal.

Comment: Can you provide the blade code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of laravel (5.5) has special blade functions for in your view:

`@auth //--no form--/ @endauth` or `@guest //--form--// @endguest`

To check if a user is authenticated you can use:

`if (Auth::check())` or `if (auth()->check())`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `auth()->guard('web')->check()`used before. Try using `Auth::user()` it will check if there is an authorized user or `Auth::guest()`

Comment: I am using a guard for multiple authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap the HTML on the blade with

```
@if(\Auth::guard('web')->check())
    <!-- Do Modal Stuff -->
@endif
```

So the modal won't even be on the page if the user isn't logged in.